# Can't get Yelp API v2 (PHP) to work

Tags: php, api, yelp

I've been all over the web and its pretty unclear to me how to get the yelp api to work using the php code sample provided.

So far I have

Grabbed the sample php file from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Yelp/yelp-api/master/v2/php/sample.php

I have not modified this file at all except to add my authentication.

Gotten all of my tokens,keys and secrets

```
$CONSUMER_KEY = "GOT IT!";
$CONSUMER_SECRET = "GOT IT!";
$TOKEN = "GOT IT!";
$TOKEN_SECRET = "GOT IT!";
```

I am including the OAuth, which I got from here http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/php/

```
require_once('OAuth.php');
```

In the read me document it states to simply go to the php file and check out the results

When I visit the page on my site, I get this error message(I removed my actual consumer key)

> `0 businesses found, querying business info for the top result ""
>   Result for business ""
>   found: {"error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE", "description": "Invalid signature. Expected signature base string: GET\u0026http%3A%2F%2Fapi.yelp.com%2Fv2%2Fbusiness%2F\u0026oauth_consumer_key%KEY%26oauth_nonce%3Db7869743b1599850a2db6e92fc2a6239%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1414090806%26oauth_token%3DyJMyLRsFiAIuKSuclV1d6pb0pwjwiEat%26oauth_version%3D1.0"}}`

I just signed up for the api keys today and have checked and double checked and they are correct in the php file.

I've also attempted to add parameters to the url to see if I can get any results and its always the same error.

My end goal is to pull in all reviews for a business by using its phone number as a search parameter. If anyone can provide an example of how I would pass the parameter that would be so helpful too.

Comment: Did you try using the `OAuth.php` from the same code repository? Here try using this file https://github.com/Yelp/yelp-api/blob/master/v2/php/lib/OAuth.php

Answer (score 0):

After getting and placing the token and secret from the app you created on Yelp. You have to edit one more thing in `Sample.php` on 13th last line (or line:138) you will see the following:

```
`$longopts  = array(
"term:: /* Place Term here e.g. 'Bars' */ ",
"location:: /* Place Location here e.g. 'San Francisco, CA' */ ",
);`
```

Or the location can be change from your Yelp Developer ID by editing the location.

Hope you got the answer.

Comment: I appreciate the response, but I don't think this is the solution. I added San Francisco to the $longopts array, but I'm getting the same error. I also dont think this absolutely has to be edited because the global variables $DEFAULT_LOCATION and $DEFAULT_TERM are set, so it should work without adding those values.

Comment: That $longopts will help in yiic YiiConsole. If you are not using framework, just try this: 
$DEFAULT_TERM = ''; // place the business name

or

query_api(/* place the business name */, /* place the city, state name */);

Answer (score 0):

To get yelp business details using phone number:

You can try a http or curl request to

http://api.yelp.com/phone_search?phone=8009773609&ywsid=sQ3g4WLACeGWOFXXXXXXXX

ywsid = Yelp CONSUMER_KEY